# MYSQL Как вычислить иерархию + 1 ко многим в одном запросе?

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many, hierarchy

Помогите понять...
Замучался я с этой иерархией, узнал, что это делается через WITH RECURSIVE, но как реализовать ещё и 1 ко многим тут же?
3адание такое:
*Получите все товары из категории **«Напитки»** и всех её подкатегорий.*
*Выведите id, имя и стоимость товара, а также название категории.*
*Название категории выведите в колонке category.*
*Данные отсортируйте по названию категории, а затем по имени товара.*
Что я делал:

```
  with recursive cte (id, name, price) as (  
  select     id,  
             name,  
             parent_id  
  from       categories  
  where      categories.name = "Напитки"  
  union all  
  select     p.id,  
             p.name,  
             p.price  
  from       products p  
  INNER join cte  
          on p.category_id = cte.id  
)  
select * from cte;
```

Исходные данные:
[image: categories]
[image: products]
На выходе я получил:

**id**  |  **name**   |  **price**
5  |Напитки| NULL
3  | Ябл сок | 112

А мне нужна и категория, и подкатегории, и товары с их айди и ценами.

Comment: *`with recursive cte (id, name, price)`* - третье поле содержит цену... но тут же *`select id, name, parent_id`* - в третье поле выбираем ссылку на родителя. Это вот вообще как?

Comment: *А мне нужна и категория, и подкатегории, и товары с их айди и ценами.* Повторю ещё раз. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3. И реши сперва хотя бы проблему с категориями, товары потом прикрутишь.

Comment: *3адание такое: Получите все товары из категории «Напитки» и всех её подкатегорий. Выведите id, имя и стоимость товара, а также название категории.* Что-то дурное задание... зачем выводить название категории, если по самому же заданию оно одно-единственное - «Напитки». Это **под**категории разные могут быть - но задание про их вывод ничего не говорит.

Comment: @Akina А в чём плох мой вопрос, собственно?
Ну очевидно, что я не шарю в этом вопросе, а только учусь.
Просто до категорий я добирался в другом задании просто с помощью JOIN
```
SELECT c2.id, c2.name as name  
FROM categories c1  
JOIN categories c2 ON c1.id = c2.parent_id  
WHERE c2.parent_id = 5  
```
Но насколько я понял, это не рекурсивный запрос.
Так что пробовал что-то новое.

Comment: *А в чём плох мой вопрос, собственно?* Безобразным оформлением.  Вот вам куча всякого, с моей проблемой внутри, авось разберётесь... вот самому за такое не стыдно? Причём один раз я уже давал ссылку на то, как надо делать, и она, судя по этому вопросу, доблестно проигнорирована. А поскольку автор вопроса должен работать над его решением как минимум не меньше остальных, то подобное оформление воспринимается как предложение оставить тебя с проблемой наедине.

Comment: @Akina Ну на самом деле я несколько раз зависал на тех ссылках. Научился строки переносить, код оформлять. Просто не очень понимаю, как лучше будет предоставить данные? Сначала отформатировал текст, далее свои данные в формате изображений (или это не приветствуется и нужно пользоваться конструктором?). Что мне нужно получить и что я пробовал делать - также написал. Я принимаю критику, без проблем проведу работу над ошибками. Но говорить в духе "а я ж вот давал ссылку!" - ну так я и не игнорил её, можете сравнить с моим предыдущим вопросом). Ну и некоторых вещей просто не освоил ещё

Comment: Пункт 5 по ссылке говорит - выложите пример данных в виде CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. Пункт 3 говорит - покажите требуемый ответ для именно этих данных, с пояснениями. Обычно такие вещи делают вручную за 5 минут. Только не надо забывать об адекватности, а то можно доупрощаться... Можно сделать online fiddle и дать ссылку - типа вот такой: https://dbfiddle.uk/OkkjR1nt

Comment: @Akina Хорошо, учёл ваши правки. Если будет возможность помочь с заданием, буду вам очень признателен. Вот ссылка с данными. 
(https://dbfiddle.uk/4pfeyPkt) 
Я тут подумал, что я ещё не проходил WITH RECURSIVE, и в задании не было помечено, что надо бы изучить эту тему самому. То есть, решаться должно другим путём, проще что-ли... А я вот совершенно не въехал, как строятся запросы с внешним ключом в этой же таблице. Может быть подскажете, как будет правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM categories
  WHERE name = 'Напитки'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT categories.*
  FROM categories
  JOIN cte ON categories.parent_id = cte.id
  )
SELECT products.id, products.name product_name, products.price, cte.name category_name
FROM cte
JOIN products ON cte.id = products.category_id;
```

| id | product_name | price | category_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Сок яблочный | 112 | Напитки |
| 6 | Забористый | 109 | Квас |
| 8 | Французское, 1 литр | 89 | Вино |
| 10 | CocaCola, 1 литр | 78 | Газировка |
| 11 | Fanta, 2 литра | 99 | Газировка |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XdoE47vk) с некоторыми пояснениями.

PS. В списке (под)категорий нет вложенности. Если её отсутствие гарантировано (хотя я не знаю, как это можно достичь средствами MySQL, даже триггеры не помогут, ибо всегда есть вариант ошибки и даже злонамеренного действия), то можно обойтись и без рекурсии, просто соединением двух копий таблицы категорий. Думаю, посмотрев на рекурсивный CTE, вы это сможете и самостоятельно...

PPS. Для понимания необходимости рекурсии измените запись `(9, 5, 'Квас')` на `(9, 16, 'Квас')`.

Comment: так, а что за вложенность? И если она есть, то в MYSQL ничего не получится сделать, правильно?

Comment: @61ack63rry *а что за вложенность?* См. PPS.